# Adding a class to an array of elements with forEach not working?

Tags: javascript

I converted a node list returned by the `querySelector()` method to an array but I still can't get forEach to work (I just want to add a class). Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My code is extremely simple as I'm very new to JS.

This is the HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>This is a th</th>
        <th>This is a th</th>
        <th>Target</th>
        <th style="display: none;"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>This is a table cell</td>
        <td>This is a table cell</td>
        <td>Target</td>
        <td style="display: none;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
(function(){

    "use strict";

    var th = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("th")),
        td = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("td"));

    function test(index, el, array) {
        el.className = "color";
    }

    th.forEach(test());


})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your argument order was wrong . This should work

```
(function(){

    "use strict";

    var th = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("th")),
        td = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("td"));

    function test(el, index, array) {
        el.className = "color";
    }

    th.forEach(test);


})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
        "use strict";
        var th = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("th")),
                td = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("td"));

        function test(el) {
            el.className = "color";
        }
        th.forEach(function(el){
            test(el);
        });
    })();
```

Try This:

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you already have `th` in forEach, so you don't need to pass it again.

then you should do it like:

```
th.forEach(test);
```

or change the test function:

```
function test() {
    return function(index, el, array){
        el.className = "color";
    };
}
th.forEach(test());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/7pVD6/

```
(function(){

    "use strict";

    var th = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("th")),
        td = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("td"));

    function test(el) {
        el.className = "color";
    }

    th.forEach(function(el)
               {
                   test(el)
               });


})();
```

You should pass a callback that takes a single argument(the element) in the forEach
or directly pass test(el)